# Wordpress get the attachment link for an image

Tags: php, wordpress

The images that I'm querying from my wordpress media gallery are appearing correctly. But, I also want them to link to my custom attachment page and I can't get it to work

```
<?php
                $query_images_args = array(
                    'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_mime_type' =>'image', 'post_status' => 'inherit', 'posts_per_page' => -1,
                );

                $query_images = new WP_Query( $query_images_args );
                $images = array();
                foreach ( $query_images->posts as $image) {
                    $images[]= wp_get_attachment_url( $image->ID );
                }
                foreach ($images as $img) {
                    $url = get_attachment_link($img->ID);
                    echo '<a href="' . $url . '">' . '<img src="' . $img . '" alt="" />' . '</a>';   
                }
            ?>
```

Comment: What exactly isn't working?

Comment: This line $url = get_attachment_link($img->ID); returns an ID of 1 every time instead of the different IDs that each image should have

Answer (score 0):

Skip the second foreach loop. You have everything you need in the first one:

```
$query_images = new WP_Query( $query_images_args );
$images = array();
foreach ( $query_images->posts as $image) {
  $images[]= wp_get_attachment_url( $image->ID );
  $url = get_attachment_link($image->ID);
  echo '<a href="' . $url . '">' . '<img src="' . wp_get_attachment_url( $image->ID ) . '" alt="" />' . '</a>';
}
```

`wp_get_attachment_url()` returns the URI of the image, see http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_url; you were trying to get the ID from this non-object.